# Editing resolved object is not updating parent/child controller data

Tags: angularjs

I am sharing data between parent and child controllers using `resolve` option available in `ui-router`. 
PFB the code,

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first/second');


        $stateProvider
            .state('first', {
                url: '/first',
                template: "<div>First Page :: Name - <input type='text' ng-model='parentName'/></div> <div ui-view=''></div>",
                resolve: {
                    name : function(){return 'Dheepan Raju';}
                },
                controller : function($scope,name){
                  $scope.parentName = name;
                }
            })
            .state('first.second', {
                url: '/second',
                template: "<div>Second Page :: Name - <input type='text' ng-model='childName'/></div>",
                controller : function($scope,name){
                  $scope.childName = name;
                }
            });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js" data-semver="1.3.15" data-require="ngRoute@1.3.15"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

            <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPG8oV9WrI7rJGKzb6tF?p=preview) is the plunker. When the page is loaded both child and parent input fields are having same name. But if I edit any of those values, it is not updating the other property. Both looks individual. How can I make both the controllers to use same data and if edit that in one controller, other controller is also updated(without any `$broadcast` or `$watch`)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a shared service with the controllers. By setting the ng-model of both to use a shared object, you can keep both controllers in sync through the service. The service handles the shared object and the controllers just reference it. No watch or broadcast required.

Updated script.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first/second');


        $stateProvider
            .state('first', {
                url: '/first',
                template: "<div>First Page :: Name - <input type='text' ng-model='parentName.name''/></div> <div ui-view=''>Hell</div>",
                resolve: {
                    name : function(){return 'Dheepan Raju';}
                },
                controller : function($scope,name, SharedData){ 
                  // Init
                  SharedData.name = name;

                  $scope.parentName = SharedData;                     
                }
            })
            .state('first.second', {
                url: '/second',
                template: "<div>Second Page :: Name - <input type='text' ng-model='childName.name'/></div>",
                controller : function($scope, SharedData){
                  $scope.childName = SharedData;
                }
            });
}).service("SharedData", function() {
  return { name: ""  }
});
```

I have updated your plunker showing this: http://plnkr.co/edit/XIvHXSy6oDuuuKsmE3AF?p=preview